# Meteor & Upstart on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, meteor, upstart

When I type the following sentence in the command line:

cd /home/username/my-meteor-app/

env PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://demo.com:27017/demo_db ROOT_URL=http://demo.com node main.js

**The app start without problems.**

**But**, when the system reboot, the **Upstart** script run but I get an error in the log.

```
[Sun Nov  8 16:52:57 ART 2015] 
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/username/my-meteor-app/bundle/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

Here, my upstart **service**: my-meteor-app.conf

start on runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

expect fork

pre-start script
end script

script
  echo "[`date`]

exec env PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://my-meteor-app.com:27017/demo_db ROOT_URL=http://my-meteor-app.com node /home/username/my-meteor-app/bundle/main.js

end script

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but you might consider using something like [`monit`](https://mmonit.com/monit/) instead, this allows you to isolate yourself from changes/differences in init systems across different distros so that you only have to ever learn one way to define your services. It's saved me a lot of time switching between old and new Ubuntu and CentOS versions for example.

Comment: What happens if you start the same command on console without cd-ing into your bundle path? I am nut sure but I guess you have to cd into the bundles directory before run node main.js

Comment: I will check monit.

If I type in the command line something like this:

env PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://demo.com:27017/demo_db ROOT_URL=http://demo.com node /home/jpmelnik/come/bundle/main.js

The Meteor App Start.

But the problem continue with upstart.